# Induced electrical field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I'm kinda confused about the law of induction of a straight wire.
Suppose I have an infinite (infinitely long and thin) wire along the z-axis with current $I=I_0 \cos(\omega t) \, e_z$. The magnetic field is then given by the Equation $$B=\frac{\mu_0 I_0}{2\pi r} \, \cos(\omega t) \, e_\varphi$$
with cylindrical coordinates $r,\varphi,z$. The field induces a rotational electric field by faraday's law of induction $$\nabla \times E = -\dot{B}=\frac{\mu_0 I_0\omega}{2\pi r} \, \sin(\omega t) \, e_\varphi \, .$$
The time-independent part of $E=(E_r \, e_r + E_\varphi \, e_\varphi + E_z \, e_z) \sin(\omega t)$ thus satisfies
$$\frac1r (\partial_\varphi E_z - \partial_z E_\varphi) e_r + (\partial_z E_r - \partial_r E_z) e_\varphi + \frac1r(\partial_r rE_\varphi - \partial_\varphi E_r) e_z=\frac{\mu_0 I_0\omega}{2\pi r} \, e_\varphi \\
\nabla \cdot E = 0$$
and the symmetry of the configuration requires $\varphi$ and $z$ independence, giving
$$E=\left(\frac{c_1}{r} \, e_r + \frac{c_2}{r} \, e_\varphi - \frac{\mu_0 I_0 \omega}{2\pi} \, \log(r/r_0) \, e_z\right) \sin(\omega t)$$ with arbitrary constants $c_1,c_2,r_0$.

Is this result correct? I'm confused about the logarithmic part diverging for large $r$ and how do I fix the contants?

Answer (score 1):

The assumed magnetic field function

$$
\mathbf B = \frac{\mu_0 I(t)}{2\pi r}\mathbf e_{\varphi}
$$

is not accurate enough for analyzing the case of oscillating current.

When we calculate curl of this assumed magnetic field, we get zero outside the wire. Using the Maxwell-Ampere law we then arrive at conclusion that electric field outside the wire does not change in time. This implies curl of electric field does not change in time, and thus $\mathbf B$ must be linear function of time.

This means that the only case where the magnetic field is correctly given by that formula is if current changes as linear function of time $\alpha t+\beta$ (or is constant in time, which is a special case of the linear function where $\alpha=0$).

Thus the assumed magnetic field is too simplistic to correctly describe electric field in the oscillating regime.

To find the actual magnetic field and electric field, we can go back to full Maxwell equations and try to solve them for the prescribed current function of time $I(t)$ on infinite line. For sinusoidal $I(t)$, the field far enough from the wire will probably look like cylindrical wave, moving away from the wire in all directions.

Comment: I see, can't just neglect the displacement-current, except in a specific case.

Answer (score 1):

I will start by motivating of the equations. You assume $B$ is the magnetostatic solution with a temporal modulation:
$$
\nabla\cdot B=0\\
\nabla\times B=\mu_0je^{i\omega t}
$$
You want to solve for $E$ satisfying:
$$
\nabla\cdot E=0\\
\nabla\times E=-\partial_tB
$$
This approach is the quasistatic approximation of the Maxwell equations. It amounts to neglecting the displacement current, and can be viewed as the leading order term in a perturbation series in $c$ (the speed of light). If you’re interested in radiation, then this not the correct way to go. However if you’re interested in the near field or low frequency regime, then it is certainly useful. Quantitatively, it works as long as:
$$
\omega r\ll c
$$

Your problem is linear, inhomogeneous and you found an inhomogeneous solution (the log term). You can always add a homogeneous solution. Examples of such homogeneous solutions is given by your three additional terms:
$$
E = \frac{c_1}{r}e_r+\frac{c_2}{r}e_\phi+c_3 e_z
$$

For a physical interpretation of this indeterminacy, your field equations are valid only for $r>0$ due to the change in cylindrical coordinates. There are two main approaches to see the problem. The first one is to only use your equations, but then the domain is space minus the $z$ axis which is topologically non trivial. Another approach is that the RHS of the equations could contain distributions supported on the $z$ axis.

For Gauss’ law, this would mean some electric charges (or higher multipoles) on the $z$ axis which would not be visible in the equation for $r>0$. The term:
$$
E\propto\frac{1}{2\pi r}e_r
$$
is a contribution of a uniform monopole. Without the symmetry requirement, you would have found additional undetermined terms with $\phi,z$ dependence like the uniform dipole along $x$ contribution:
$$
E\propto\frac{1}{2\pi r^2}(\cos\phi e_r+\sin\phi e_\phi)
$$
In your case, there are no charges, so $c_1=0$.

For the curl, the equations are the same as in magnetostatics assuming zero divergence. You can therefore have terms corresponding to magnetic multipole on the axis. Your term:
$$
E\propto\frac{1}{2\pi r}e_\phi
$$
corresponds to the uniform moment along $z$ contribution.

Physically, those multipole terms would correspond to an additional magnetic field localized on the axis. This magnetic field must be generated by other currents according to magnetostatics (still in the quasistatic approximation). Your $c_2$ term corresponds to an infinitely thin solenoid about the $z$ axis. This is why $c_2=0$ in your example.

Thus your symmetry requirement is an efficient way of getting rid of unwanted multipolar fields that are not relevant for your situation. In the same vein, you can use more symmetries to get rid of $c_1,c_2$. Any plane passing by the $z$ axis are planes of symmetry, so $B$ is orthoradial. Furthermore, any plane perpendicular to the $z$ axis are planes of antisymmetry, so $E$ is along $z$.

Finally, for your third term, it arises from logarithm. This divergence analogous to the log divergence of the electric field about a uniformly charged wire. Essentially, it shows that an isolated wire is not physical, and they always come in pairs of opposing currents like in waveguides (this is a form of confinement). Therefore the leading order logarithms cancel out leaving only a $1/r$ decay at infinity. Continuing the electrostatic analogue, only the 2D dipole contribution survives, the monopole contribution is cancelled, so you’d expect:
$$
E\sim\frac{\mu_0I_0\omega d}{2\pi r}(\cos\phi e_r+\sin\phi e_\phi)
$$
with with the opposing line of current being at a distance $d$ along the $x$ direction with respect to the $z$ axis.

Thus the additive constant $c_3$ must be chosen in accordance with the other line’s constant so that they cancel and the field decays to zero at infinity. A pedestrian approach would be to realize that you need a characteristic length to make the argument of the logarithm dimensionless. In your original problem, there are none, so this is why it is ill defined. Adding another opposing wire introduces a new length: their relative distance.

The logarithmic divergence for large $r$ is an artefact of the quasistatic approximation. The radiating field does decay at infinity. Using the displacement current, your equations become (setting $\mu_0=c=I_0=1$):
$$
-E_z’=-i\omega B_\phi\\
\frac{1}{r}(rB_\phi)’=i\omega E_z
$$
Ampère’s law gives the “initial condition”:
$$
2\pi rB_r \xrightarrow{r\to 0} 1
$$
The simplest solution is:
$$
\begin{align}
B_\phi &=-\frac{\omega}{4}Y_1(r\omega)\\
&\sim \frac{1}{2\pi r} &&r\to 0\\
&\sim \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2\pi r}}\cos(r\omega)&& r\to\infty \\
E_z &= \frac{i\omega}{4}Y_0(r\omega) \\
&\sim \frac{i\omega}{2\pi }\ln(r\omega) && r\to 0\\
&\sim \frac{i}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2\pi r}}\sin(r\omega)&& r\to\infty
\end{align}
$$
Thus the fields do decay to zero. You still have infinite energy (diverges linearly). Furthermore, due to the quarter phase offset, there is no mean radiated power. Note that adding a line of opposite current will give finite energy.

There is still an indeterminacy as you can always add solutions of the form:
$$
\begin{align}
B_\phi &= iCJ_1(r\omega)\\
E_z &= CJ_0(r\omega) 
\end{align}
$$
with an undetermined $C$. This is analogous to your indeterminate $c_3$ (or $r_0$). Again, these do not radiate power and also contribute to infinite energy. As in the static case, you can get finite energy solutions with an opposite line current and the $C$ terms are matched to cancel out to give finite energy solutions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: $\nabla \times \mathbf E = 0$ does not hold except in static case where $\mathbf B = const.$, or specific instants when $\partial \mathbf B/\partial t = 0$.

Comment: Circulation of $\mathbf E$ has nothing to do with charge distribution on the z axis. For field $\frac{c_2}{2\pi r} \mathbf e_{\varphi}$, circulation is non-zero but does not depend on radius, so curl of such field vanishes except on the z axis.

Comment: Just wondering, if I have a current along the $z$-axis, does it necessarily represent a charge distribution as well? I mean, this is how I interpret this answer, because I was actually only considering a current, not a charge.

Comment: @JánLalinský yes for the second charge density commentary, it was just a bad copy paste. For your first comment, I don’t see how it’s relevant. I’m just looking at the homogeneous solutions, the discussion is purely mathematical.

Comment: @Diger It’s rather an “option. The formalism allows you to add a uniform charge distribution (since you are looking at $z$ invariant solutions). If you set $c_1=0$, then there will be no charge.

Comment: The relevance is that electric field with zero curl is wrong for the assumed situation - the correct field has to have non-zero curl in general (that can be zero only at special position and time).

Comment: I see, anyway. I think Jan's answer is more what I was actually looking for, but I wouldn't mind if you elaborate specifically on the last point about the log-divergence and how it arises and cancels with two wires?

Comment: The electric field obeys $\nabla \times \mathbf E = - \frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}$, but this equation is not enough to find the fields, we need the other equation $\nabla \times \mathbf B = \mu_0 \mathbf j + \mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}$ too. I think it makes no sense to seek solutions to only $\nabla \times \mathbf E = 0$ here, the magnetic term is important.

Comment: The OP used the quasistatic approximation, so I just focused on its consistencies. Taking into account the displacement current is not always necessary.

Comment: @LPZ displacement current is vital here: if we assume it vanishes, magnetic field is restricted to be a linear function of time, and OP assumes oscillating current, which will have oscillating magnetic field.

Comment: No, with an oscillating current, the magnetic field will be oscillating as well. Even the OP’s solution shows oscillations, as usual, the electric and magnetic field are merely in quadrature.

Comment: > *"Essentially, it shows that an isolated wire is not physical, and they always come in pairs of opposing currents like in waveguides (this is a form of confinement). "* Isolated wire certainly is physical, and they do not always come in pairs. *Infinite wire*, isolated or not, is unphysical.