# Infinite/recursive solution for magnetic field due to a long straight wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, maxwell-equations

I'm trying to use Maxwell-Ampere's law to find the field due to a long straight wire, but I keep running into some circular reasoning...

Maxwell-Ampere's law states that $\oint_c \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0 \iint (\vec{J_e} + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}) \cdot \vec{dA}$. My thinking is that if there exists a time-varying current, that must also mean that there exists a time-varying electric potential difference, which then also means that there must be a time-varying electric field. That electric field would give way to a new induced current opposing the original one (due to the rules of self-inductance). Let's call this new current $I_i$, as opposed to the original current, $I_0$.

Here's where the recursive issue comes in:

$I_0$ will induce a current, $I_i$. But $I_i$ is a current on its own merits, no different than the original current, so $I_i$ will also induce another current, $I_{ii}$, which will then produce ANOTHER current, $I_{iii}$...and so on. By this reasoning, I never get to actually solve for the magnetic field because I keep running into new currents to solve for the field of.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think there should be a simple solution? There isn't unless you assume a steady current, or at least one that varies slowly enough that the displacement current term can be ignored.

Comment: You're trying to use causal statements about imaginary currents that do not actually exist, this is not how fields in a given situation are usually sought. Instead, use mathematics to find solution of the equation for the given (single,real) current. The equation refers to single current density $J$ and single electromagnetic field $B,E$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your solution does converge. It turns out that you can solve analytically the case of an infinite line current. Check out the solution [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/777340/333454). Just to clarify, the proper way to think about it is that from Ampère's law you have a varying magnetic field. From Faraday's law, this induces an electric field. It will in turn give a displacement current which you can interpret as your additional currents $I_i$.

Your method will basically give the asymptotic expansion of the Bessel functions in the $r\to0$ (equivalently, $\omega\to0$ or $c\to\infty$). You can find a similar reasoning in the [*Feynman Lectures on Physics* (Vol II - Ch 23)](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_23.html).

Hope this helps.